# How to fix stmt prepare and bind

Tags: php, mysqli, prepare, bindparam

I am having trouble using this prepare and bind. I have tried the same thing with less variables to bind. I have been successful using prepare with just Fname, Lname, Password, $UserID and using sssi with the bind_param object. Can someone explain what I am doing wrong when using more variables in my bind code? With the code below it only prints out the same data from mysqli and doesn't update it.

```
if ($stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE users SET Fname = ?, Lname = ?, Password = ?, UserLevel = ?, Email = ?, WHERE UserID= ?"))
{
    $stmt->bind_param("ssssssi", $firstname, $lastname, $PW, $UserLevel, $EM, $UserID);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
}
// show an error message if the query has an error
else
{
    echo "ERROR: could not prepare SQL statement.";
}

// redirect the user once the form is updated
header("Location: admin.php");
```

Comment: You have too many `ssss`'s

Comment: what is 'sssssi' in $stmt->bind_param("ssssssi", $firstname, $lastname, $PW, $UserLevel, $EM, $UserID); code?

Comment: and `Email = ?,` < *is killing it too Sam* @JayBlanchard - @ OP, You're not checking for errors. This `echo "ERROR: could not prepare SQL statement.";` does nothing. This http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php  does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you haven't specified the data types which makes this tricky, I'll hazard a guess.

`Fname = s`

`Lname = s`

`Password = s`

`UserLevel = i` (?)

`Email = s`

I count 4 s' there, yet you have **6**.

Try this,

```
 $stmt->bind_param("sssisi", $firstname, $lastname, $PW, $UserLevel, $EM, $UserID);
```

**Edit 1**

As @Fred-ii- said, your SQL query is wrong.

Change

```
"UPDATE users SET Fname = ?, Lname = ?, Password = ?, UserLevel = ?, Email = ?, WHERE UserID= ?"
```

to,

```
"UPDATE users SET Fname = ?, Lname = ?, Password = ?, UserLevel = ?, Email = ? WHERE UserID= ?"
```

You had a training `,`.

Comment: You were right I misplaced a comma after directing where I wanted the changes to take place for that UserID the code is working now. Also, for placing the sssisi, is it necessary to place an i for every integer.

Comment: @alstonan25 glad to help.